# Is there any way to get a 'Watched' Tag for Video files in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, file-management

Is there any way to add a watched tag *automatically* on video files in windows explorer for the videos that are partially/completely watched? Something like youtube.com does.

If partially watched and completely watched videos can be separated, that would be great. I have been trying to implement this using the 'details' option in explorer, but couldn't find any option.

Is there some way to do this?

Edit- I found this *Date Visited* detail in exlporer but it doesnot show anything! Can we use that?

Comment: Only if you rename the file or move it to another folder.

Comment: I meant automatically not manually! Just after you watch a video, it gets a tag!

Comment: Yeah, that would be cool. I don't know any apps/plugins that do that... I always write down the last videos name.

Comment: I remember Windows Media Player had such feature in its library. It kept a playback count.

Comment: Seriously though, if you don't remember them, isn't watching them a waste of time in the first place? If it was not a waste of time, then consider them unwatched and watch them again. It is not a waste of time this time either.